# Magento 2: How to use multiple fieldsets using uiComponents?

Tags: uicomponent, adminform, magento2.2, fieldsets

I want to have multiple fieldsets under the same tab using uiComponents.
There is something similar under `Stores -> Attributes -> Product` but it's created using an old deprecated method.

Is there a way to achieve this using uiComponents?

This is what I have until now:

```
<fieldset name="module_shipping_address">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Shipping Address</label>
    </settings>
    <field name="email" formElement="input">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">module_shipping</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="validate-email" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <visible>true</visible>
        </settings>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

If I add a new fieldset a new tab will be created. Is there a way to achieve what I want using **uiComponents**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to achieve this is to wrap your fieldsets inside another `<fieldset>`

```
<fieldset name="module">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Module</label>
    </settings>
    <fieldset name="module_shipping_address">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Shipping Address</label>
        </settings>
        <field name="email" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">module_shipping</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="validate-email" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="module_billing_address">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Billing Address</label>
        </settings>
        <field name="email" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">module_billing</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="validate-email" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```